# Draw Multiple figures in a stage using Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I want to draw multiple figures on a canvas on different button clicks.

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container">
</div>

<div id="option">
<button value="rect" onclick="rect();">rect</button>
<button value="circle" onclick="circle();">circle</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      });
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

function rect(){
var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [100, 5, 100, 300, 450,300],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        lineCap: 'square',
        lineJoin: 'mitter'
      });
// add the shape to the layer

layer.add(redLine);
// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);
}

function circle(){
      var wedge = new Kinetic.Wedge({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 70,
        angleDeg: 60,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        rotationDeg: -120
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(wedge);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
}
```

But it gives error as layer and stage are not defined. How do I solve it ?

Comment: can you put your code in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons that stage and layer would not be defined are that either they are outside of scope, or your code is breaking before they are instantiated in the first place.

First, make sure that your stage and layer are outside of any functions; global scope.

Second, your functions 'circle()' and 'rect()' are being called with the button click, which I suspect is breaking your code. You want to remove this onclick handler from inline:

```
 <button value="circle" onclick="circle();">circle</button>
```

and assign onclick using javascript, after you have created your stage. You can assign handlers easily using jQuery. So your code should look something like:

HTML

```
<button value="rect" id='rect'>rect</button>  //assign an id to your button
```

JS

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  });
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

$('#yourButtonId').click(function(){ // button id here would be '#rect' if you use the id above
    rect();
});
```